# Rails Knock jwt config more than one param to login on the entity model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

after setup a simple auth with knock i'd like to add a extra param to auth_params,

in the docs the config is via-the-entity-model

```
    def self.from_token_request request
    # Returns a valid user, `nil` or raise `Knock.not_found_exception_class_name`
    # e.g.
    #   email = request.params["auth"] && request.params["auth"]["email"]
    #   self.find_by email: email
  end
```

So i presumed so

```
def self.from_token_request(request)
    email = request.params["auth"] && request.params["auth"]["email"]
    confirmation_email = request.params["auth"] && request.params["auth"]["confirmation_email"]
    self.find_by(email: email, confirmation_email: confirmation_email)
  end
```

And after a post to UserTokenController 
that is config to

```
def auth_params
    params.require(:auth).permit(:email, :password, :confirmation_email)
  end
```

Did not generated the  token nor the :confirmation_email params was used and caused 404 error!

the logs

> Processing by UserTokenController#create as */*   Parameters:
>   {"auth"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"manolo@manolo.com"},
>   "user_token"=>{"auth"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "email"=>"manolo@manolo.com"}}}   User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "users".*
>   FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND
>   "users"."confirmation_email" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["email",
>   "manolo@manolo.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳ app/models/user.rb:51
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 96ms (ActiveRecord: 15.3ms)

So, please someone can clarify how to config the knock gem to login with more than email params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def auth_params
      params.permit auth: [:phone, :pin, :has_access]
   end`

` def self.from_token_request

```
    phone = request.params[:auth]&& request.params[:auth][:phone]
  has_access= request.params[:auth]&& request.params[:auth][:has_access]
  self.find_by phone: phone, has_access: has_access
```

end
`

If you have submitted the offer on upwork. I am sent a proposal to help you

Answer (score 0):

I had to test the code by adding a second parameter for the connection and it works well on my side
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHi7N.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add the actual code and a description rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Moufid, thank you very much, indeed is working but, just if the params is present i'd like to know if possible if just the boolean is set to true